# $L_1$ inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

$\tilde{f} =\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(x+k)$, where $f$ is an $L_1$ function with Lebesgue measure $\mu$. Show that $||\tilde{f} ||_{L_1} \leq ||f ||_{L_1}$

Comment: Please add your attempts.

Comment: This is not much more than a straightforward consequence of the triangle inequality and the fact that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x+k)|\,dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|\,dx$ if $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 0):

since I can't post comments I write this as an answer.

I am sure that this won't work, because you need additionally that $\tilde{f} \in L_1$.
Then you can follow the hint of Jack D'Aurizio.

But if you can't assume that, then $f = 1_{[0,1)}$ is a counterexample.
Because
$$
\tilde{f}_{n} := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 1_{[0,1)}(x+k)
= \frac{1}{n} 1_{[-n+1,1)}(x).
$$
Now it is easy to check that $\|\tilde{f}_n\| = 1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. So if $\tilde{f}_n$ converts in $L_1$ then the norm must be $1$. But if you regard the series $\tilde{f}_n$ pointwise then the limit is $0$ which contradicts with the previous statement.

Comment: But OP didn't say that $\lim_n \sum_{0\le k< n} f(x+k)$ converges in $L^1$. The convergence is only pointwise. So $\lim_n \tilde{f_n}=0$ does not contradict the statement: $\|\lim_n \tilde{f}_n\|\le \|f\|$.

Comment: That is true, but I wanted to point out that the given sequence does not automatically converge if you start with an $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, since the suggested proof of Jack D'Aurizio uses that property.

Comment: Oh, I just realized that this answer was written almost 2 years ago ... Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $g(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(x+k)$ converges almost everywhere pointwise, we can show that $\|g\|_{L^1}\le \|f\|_{L^1}$ as follows. Let $g_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(x+k)$. Note that
$$
|g_n(x)|\le \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|f(x+k)|
$$ and hence
$$
|g(x)|=\lim_{n\to\infty}|g_n(x)|\le \liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|f(x+k)|.
$$ By Fatou's lemma it follows
$$
\|g\|_{L^1}\le \int_\mathbb{R} \left[\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|f(x+k)|\right]\;d\mu\le\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|f(x+k)|d\mu=\|f\|_{L^1}.
$$